# integration of floor function

Tags: calculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How to Integrate the following?
$$\int_{2}^{343}\{x-\lfloor{x}\rfloor\}^2dx = \int_{2}^{3}x^2dx + \int_{3}^{4}x^2dx+\cdots+\int_{342}^{343}x^2dx$$

This is what I did, How can I proceed further with this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do the {} denote fractional part of x?

Comment: You should clearly state, what’s your question. To evaluate the first integral?

Comment: You problem is just to calculate the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\{x-\lfloor{x}\rfloor\}^2dx$ (which is equal to $\dfrac13$ and then multiply correctly (all the the partial integrals should be equal).

Comment: @AAM the difference of any real number and it's integer part will be the fractional part so I think it's the fractional part too but the question did not state it.

Comment: @Piquito could you please explain briefly how did you change the bounds of integration ?

Comment: @econhead I guess either way it doesnt matter as {{x}} is just {x} even if {} is fractional part of x.

Comment: WARNING: I have take your function as $\int_{0}^{1}(x-\lfloor{x}\rfloor)^2dx$. Now i doubt about the fractional pàrt instead.

Comment: okay thanks, do you have any ideas about this problem? @AAM

Comment: @Piquito the problem did not state that {} represents the fractional part but your solution to the problem is correct could you please elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: @econhead if you check behavior of fractional part of x its a periodic function with periodcity 1 so integral from n to n+1 where n is an integer should be same I guess.

Comment: btw guys any idea why my meagre reputation keeps on getting low? i can not even upvote questions because of this

Comment: @econhead: Why you do have $\int_{0}^{1}(x-\lfloor{x}\rfloor)^2dx=\int_0^1x^2dx$? Think a bit on this. (Don't worry about "meagre reputation" you are young and you have all you can reach in your life)-

Comment: thank you, @Piquito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of separating the integral in integer intervalls was correct.

You have

$$
\int_n^{n+1} \left(x-\lceil x \rceil \right)^2dx=\int_n^{n+1} (x-n)^2dx=\frac{1}{3}
$$
so
$$
I=\sum_{n=2}^{342} \frac{1}3=\frac{341}3
$$

**Edit:**

As noted in the comments of the OP, as the fractional part function is periodic with period 1 would have been enought to calculate
$$
\int_0^1 x^2 dx
$$

Comment: hi, I am not familiar with this periodicity of the fractional part function could you please explain why the bounds of integration are 0 and 1?

Comment: @econhead look at the graph of the fractional part function.  You have $$ \{x\}=\{x+1\}$$ for any $x$ (for the definition of the fractional part). So you have
$$\int_0^1 \{x\}^2 dx=\int_0^1 x^2 dx= \int_n^{n+1} \{x\}^2 dx$$ but the  first integral is simplest to calculate

Comment: thank you, btw shouldn't the sum be equal to 341/3? i think you made a typo